# Can a service managed by systemd send its logs somewhere other than /var/log/messages?

Tags: logging, systemd, systemctl

We have a RHEL 8 server where we have a few python applications installed for data management and analysis, notably JupyterHub and Airflow. We have these set up with systemd unit files so we can start, stop, restart them using `systemctl` and we access their logs using `journalctl`. Our infrastructure folks in charge of the server have kindly asked to make sure our applications send their log messages to somewhere other than `/var/log/messages` so they can debug server health without having our applications "polluting" the log. But we have not been able to identify a solution to this.

Is there a way to configure a `systemd` service so its logs aren't going to `/var/log/messages`?
If not, what could we be using instead of `systemd` that exist within the RHEL ecosystem?

Answer (score 3):

systemd doesn't send logs to `/var/log/messages`; it writes things to the system journal (which you read using [`journalctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/journalctl.html)).

If something is writing to `/var/log/messages`, it's a syslog program like [syslog-ng](https://www.syslog-ng.com/) or [rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/), which is reading from the journal and then writing to files in `/var/log`. If you want to change that, update your syslog server configuration (or disable it, if you don't want to write there at all).

RHEL systems typically use rsyslog, configured in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (and `/etc/rsyslog.d`).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was "as easy" as using the [`StandardOutput`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) and [`StandardError`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#StandardError=) variables in the service file.

```
StandardOutput=append:/path/to/airflow-scheduler.log
StandardError=append:/path/to/airflow-scheduler.log
```

But now we would need to figure out a way to make sure those get rotated.